# Anyway to close this window?

Tags: javascript

Is there anyway to get the "loadedafter15seconds.com"
to close after 20 seconds?

code at http://pastebin.com/480TtqJ9

**Basically i want a button that goes to a page. That page loads a list of urls after a certain amount of time and then closes them after a certain amount of time.**

Comment: Please specify the requirement in detail..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[DEMO on Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nawazhi/PueNn/1/)

```
function closeWindow() {
setTimeout(function() {
window.close();
}, 15000);
}
```

**EDIT**

Use it like this

```
 function NewWindow3() 
   {    
    win = window.open('http://www.loadedafter15seconds.com') 
    setTimeout(function() { win.close(); }, 20000);
    }
```

Comment: How exactly would i implement that ? I try `<script type="text/javascript">
windowevent=window.setTimeout("NewWindow3()",15000);
function NewWindow3() {
window.open('http://www.loadedafter15seconds.com')
}
function closeWindow() {
setTimeout(function() {
window.close();
}, 20000);
}

</script> 
` nothin happen